# React Native : Execute function to change app state when it's inactive (still running on background)

Tags: javascript, react-native, background

Im working on music application when it'is innactive (i click on home button) i can't run my JS function to play next music, is there any way to execute my function in another thread (that share state with main thread) when react-native application is innactive?